# найти одинаковое в 3 списках

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм

Есть 3 списка:

```
lst_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lst_2 = [1, 6, 7, 5, 2]
lst_3 = [2, 3, 4, 8, 9]
```

Как с помощью цикла найти числа, присутствующие во всех списках?

Comment: а вам обязательно цикл для этого нужен?

Comment: а списки отсортированы?

Answer (score 5):

Наиболее эффективным способом здесь будет пересечение множеств:

```
res = list(set(lst_1) & set(lst_2) & set(lst_3))

print(res)
# [2]
```

Comment: так не работает

Comment: @Maks, что значит не работает? выдает ошибку? какую?

Answer (score 0):

Если принципиально цикл нужен, то вот:

```
result =[]
for el in set(lst_1):
    if el in lst_2 and el in lst_3:
        result.append(el)
```

Либо можно с помощью генератора списка

```
result =[el for el in set(lst_1) if el in lst_2 and el in lst_3]
```